# Am new to firebase and cant seem to order my data i have tried using query and orderBy()

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

i have tried using query and orderBy() and firstly cant even properly fit it into my code

methods:

```
async saveMessage(){
  try {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "chat"), {
      message:this.message,
      createdAt: new Date()
    });
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
  }
  this.message= null;
},

async fetchMessages(){

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db,"chat"));
     let allMessages = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{
      allMessages.push(doc.data());
    })
    this.messages = allMessages;
  }
},
```

Comment: "cant even properly fit it into my coder" Can you elaborate on what that means? When you step through this code line by line in a debugger and inspect all variables on each line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: i meant i dont seem to know where to add the orderBy() In the code read from the documentation of firebase

Answer (score 0):

To order results, you add a query with an ordering clause:

```
import { query, orderBy, ... } from "firebase/firestore";  

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(query(collection(db,"chat"), orderBy("name")));
```

I recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [ordering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data), from where I got the changes I made to your code.